# How to download an image from Ionic image gallery?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using Ion-gallery directive and displaying images inside ion-gallery using image url. How can I download the same image?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you check the answer ?

Comment: Did you added permission for Android Marshmallow or higher.

Comment: Still you have error after MediaScannerPlugin

Comment: No, I havn't tried it yet. But the basic error is that i am unable to download the file in Marshmallow but for kitkat it works fine. How can I get permission from user for storage for Marsmallow or higher.

Comment: yes its working for higher version https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gallery-does-not-show-the-image-after-download/13477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this you want to use `ng-cordova File Transfer Plugin` from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).

In this plugin you have to option to download file and store in your sd card.

**Source Code Example** :

```
            $scope.downloadFile = function() {
               //URL CONTAINTS IMAGE PATH
               var url = "http://your_ip_address/images/my.jpg";
               var filename = url.split("/").pop();
               alert(filename);
               var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
               var trustHosts = true
               var options = {};
               alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
               $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                 .then(function(result) {
                   // Success!
                   alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                 }, function(error) {
                   // Error
                   alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                 }, function (progress) {
                   $timeout(function () {
                     $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                   })
                 });
            }
```

Still If you are having issue then reason for images not to show up in the gallery is because the Android Media needs to be updated after doing downloads or creation of folders. I have the same issue but I think I found a solution [here](https://github.com/peteygao/MediaScannerPlugin).

This is a plugin that allows Cordova to invoke Media Scanner just by using:

```
 window.MediaScannerPlugin(successCallback, failureCallback)
```

for more help please look to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html), [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gallery-does-not-show-the-image-after-download/13477) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255757/gallery-does-not-show-the-image-after-download).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: yes, I have already done that, the only issue with this is that, after downloading through cordova file transfer plugin, it's doesn't displaying in gallery. I need to manually go to specified path to find the image.

Comment: please check the answer , I have updated it Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Yeah I have added the above code, but the issue is that cordova-file transfer works for android but only for lower version then Marshmallow.        How to get permissions from User device for Android Marshmallow or higher.